# Candy Machine Assets Skipping Numbers In File Names

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine, solana-cli

I am working to upload some assets to Candy Machine V2 but there are several NFT's/metadata that I need to remove from the collection. So in a collection of 3500, I need to remove 5 of them (for example - numbers 655, 1001, 2000, 2002, and 3001). I know that the assets need to start at the number 0 (i.e. 0.png and 0.json) but does it cause issues if there are file names that are skipping numbers. So after I remove the above 5, I'll have something like the following in the assets folder:

```
0.png
0.json
1.png
1.json
.
.
.
654.png
654.json
- now missing 655.png and 655.json
656.png
656.json
.
.
etc.
```

Is it an issue to be missing 655.png and 655.json? Do I need to go through and update the file names for everything so that 656.png is now 655.png, etc?

Comment: I see this in the Metaplex Docs: The first item in your collection must have the index 0, the second 1 and so forth. In a 10000 NFT drop, will start with the pair 0.png and 0.json, and end with the pair 9999.png and 9999.json. The numbering must also be consecutive - i.e., should not have gaps in the numbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**official metaplex docs**](https://docs.metaplex.com/tools/sugar/preparing-assets) said that you must check that your asset folder has ***N*** images and ***N*** json files with names starting from ***0*** to ***N-1***, not following this can cause issues on the minting (NFTs without metadata) or you dont even will be able to upload.

In order to remove ***X*** metadata files from ur asset folder you should create a really simple script (using python or other programing language) that iterates ur asset folder, creates a new one with the files you wanna remove and renamin all the remaining files.

Answer (score 0):

Or if it’s just 5 that you have to do (and you don’t know how to make a script) you could edit the names of the png and json

For example if you had 0-99 delete the 5 you want rid off and then rename the last 5 (95-99) to the numbers you just deleted.

Within the json files of the ones your renaming there is a also a ##.png reference that you will have to change too.

Always try it on devnet first and use the verify tool to check everything is good before upload

I done this before when my collection generated started at 1.png so I renamed 5555.png to 0 like above and it worked a charm